# Increase priority in priority queue

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue

I want to decrease the priority of an element in a priority queue? How do I achieve that in logarithmic time?

I know priority queues are implemented as max heaps. But if I modify any element in the queue and then call make_heap on it, it will take linear time in the number of elements.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

Comment: Well, you just answered your own question, didn't you? Unless I'm missing something, you just demonstrated that this can't be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to perform updating with logarithmic complexity is to implement the priority queue yourself, so you can use [well-known algorithms](https://www.google.com/search?q=heap+decrease-key+increase-key).

The implementation of `std::priority_queue` is not specified by the standard (for example it can well be [d-ary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap)), so you can't portably update the priority without rebuilding the queue. For the same reason you can't use `std::make_heap` and related functions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it using `std::priority_queue`. However, it is possible if you have an access to the internal structure of the heap. If you have a pointer to the element, you can decrease the priority of an element and then use `siftDown` procedure for this element only to fix the heap.